# Ensure spyOnProperty creates configurable properties with Object.defineProperty

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ts-mockito

In an upgrade to Angular 9 (from 8.1) and Typescript 3.7 (from <3.6), I have encountered an issue with `spyOnProperty`

My service looks like:

```
class Backend {
  public get baseURL(): string {
    return 'http://baseurl.com/';
  }
}
```

My test that worked before the upgrade would `spyOnProperty`

```
spyOnProperty(backend, 'baseURL', 'get').and.returnValue('http://new');
```

However, I am now getting this error:

```
Error: <spyOnProperty> : baseURL is not declared configurable
Usage: spyOnProperty(<object>, <propName>, [accessType])
```

I know that I need to `Object.defineProperty` as `configurable: true`, as when stepping through Jasmine I see it fails at:

```
if (!descriptor.configurable) {
  throw new Error(
    getErrorMsg(propertyName + ' is not declared configurable')
  );
}
```

And `descriptor` is created by `descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, methodName);`

So in Javascript I would want to:

```
Object.defineProperty(backend.prototpye, 'baseURL', {value: 'http://new', configurable: true});
```

To ensure that this property could be spied on.

However, my question is how do I apply the same configurable with Typescript. I have tried to run `Object.defineProperty` again but I get an error `defineproperty Cannot redefine property`, which makes sense as to why the check is there in the first place.

I tried using the suggested `configurable` decorator defined [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html):

```
function configurable(value: boolean) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        descriptor.configurable = value;
    };
}
```

But this does not work, also to note that when I put a breakpoint inside the above method, the `descriptor.configurable` is actually already set to `true` before assigning the `value`. So I am not sure what is actually causing the original error in the tests.

Answer (score 0):

I missed some additional information about creating my tests. To create an instance of the injected services I am using, [ts-mockito](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mockito) to create an `instance()` of each class.

I think it was this call to `instance()` that was creating properties as not configurable.

Effectively:

```
service = new Service(instance(new Backend));
```

Changed to:

```
service = new Service(new Backend);
```

Resolves the issue

Comment: I have notice as well spy on ts-mockito is falling with document and elements, so spy(document) use to work, but now I get an error of property can not be redefined